# Get nginx running status as bool

Tags: linux, nginx

I would like to have a nginx-status-bool for my script to check if its running (true) or not (false). If I use "sudo service nginx status" I will get the whole info, but I would like a way to only get true/false back.

- Ubuntu
- used in PHP-script (not important tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `systemctl` commands follow [LSB semantics](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html) for exit codes.

Specifically, `systemctl status nginx` will exit with code `3` if the program is not running, and `0` if it is running.

Launching a program and getting its exit code should be fairly trivial like:

```php
<?php

exec('systemctl status nginx', $out, $exit_code);
if (0 == $exit_code) {
    echo 'NGINX is running';
} elseif (3 == $exit_code) {
    echo 'NGINX is stopped';
}
```

P.S. you don't have to run `systemctl` with `sudo`. It should work for unprivileged user.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of interest: How would you get the exit code via terminal? Because if I run the code in terminal its about the same as "service nginx status"

Comment: Simply `echo $?`